# What privileges should a MySQL user have?

Tags: 7, database

When I am creating a user for my Drupal in cPanel, it asks me to check all privileges. What privileges should be enabled, to make Drupal work correctly?

Currently, my user has all privileges except *Drop permission*.

Comment: It is rather odd that  http://drupal.org/requirements#database never got updated for the permissions for Drupal 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For development you'll need essentially everything - including drop. Once you go live, drop is generally not needed.

That said, if you're allowing delete - for instance - then drop isn't much more drastic. If someone owns your server, deleting all the rows from your tables is pretty much as bad as dropping a table - either way, the only good fallback is proper backups.

Setup your database user to only be allowed to connect from the host Drupal is running on. And make sure if that host has ssh allowed, you're using keys, and not just username/password, and you should be pretty good.

Comment: DROP can be needed on a live system if you uninstall a module, and its hook_uninstall() does a DROP TABLE.

Comment: True. I guess by "live" I assume people won't be uninstalling modules live, but I know that happens more than maybe it should.

Comment: I also figured out clearing cache also need DROP enabled.

Answer (score 2):

Drupal 7 needs this permissions for work correctly: SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, INDEX, ALTER, LOCK TABLES, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES

Answer (score 1):

There are really two issues here.

One is the requirements that core Drupal needs.  The other is requirements that non-core modules need.

You can determine what core Drupal needs, but the non-core modules can be a little tougher.

Since I may not know what I may need in the future, or what a client may install once they get the keys to the site, I will give a localhost-only user all permissions except for **GRANT**.